# WIndows 10 で express コマンドが見つからない

Tags: node.js, windows-10, express.js

タイトルの件で現在学習を進められず困っております。
以下に事象までの手順を記しました。何卒皆様の知識をご教示いただければと思います。

**解消したい事象**
expressコマンドを使えるようにしたい。

**インストール**
公式サイトからインストーラをダウンロードし、そのままインストールしました。
（verは16.13.1 LTS、設定は特に変えてません。)

**npmコマンドでExpress-generatorをインストール**
npmコマンドを使用して、Express及びExpress-generatorをグローバルインストールしました。
[image: 画像はインストール時の状況です。]

インストール後、念の為ルートフォルダを確認しました。
下図の通り、ルートフォルダには問題なくパッケージがインストールされているっぽいです。
[image: プロンプト]
[image: フォルダ]

**Expressコマンドでアプリケーションを作成…できず…**
必要なパッケージをインストールできましたので、
公式サイトのガイド(https://expressjs.com/ja/starter/hello-world.html)を参考にlocalhost:3030に「Hello world」出力までを行いました。

このとき、ソースコード上の

```
const express = require('express')
```

は問題なく動いたため、expressは正常に稼働できると考えておりました。

その後、expressコマンドを使用してWebアプリケーションを作成しようとしましたが、

```
$express -v ejs express-app
```

expressコマンドが見つからず、完全に詰まってしまいました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**他に試してみたこと**
グローバルインストールで駄目だったので、デスクトップにローカルインストールも試してみましたが、同じようにコマンドが見つかりませんでした…
[image: ローカルインストール]

以上が手順になります。

ほか必要な情報がありましたらご連絡いただけますと幸いです。
お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

### PATHが通っているか確認してください

コントロールパネルの「環境変数を編集」から(スタートメニューで検索すると速いです)、ユーザー環境変数の`PATH`にnpmのパッケージのグローバルインストール先のパスが入っているか確認してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もし、ここに`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`がないのであれば追加してください。(`%USERPROFILE%`の部分は実際にはユーザーのホームディレクトリ)

インストーラーをデフォルトの状態で進めていたのであれば、すでに入っているはずです。
(様々なものをインストールしていると、時に文字数オーバーで追加できない場合があります。)

あってもなくても、現在開いているコマンドプロンプトやPowerShellなどを一旦すべて閉じて開きなおすかPCの再起動を行ってください。(多分再起動は不要ですが、そっちのほうが確実)

`express`コマンドは利用できるようになりましたか？なお、`express`コマンドは`express`パッケージではなく`express-generator`に含まれています。

### npxで呼び出す

npmにはnpxというツールコマンドが用意されています。これを利用すると、パスが通っていなくてもインストールされているnpmで提供されるパッケージのコマンドや、あるいは明示的にインストールしていないものについても実行することが可能です。

```
npx express --version
```

ローカル、グローバル、自動インストール、の優先度で探索・実行が行われる筈です。(ただし、明示的にインストールしていない場合、express-generatorはパッケージ名が異なるのでそちらを指定する必要があります)

Comment: ただ、`npm`にパスが通っているのにnpm rootの方にパスが通っていないのも不自然な感じもします。

Comment: 様 ご確認いただきありがとうございます！ユーザー環境変数を確認したところ、こちらにrootまでのパスがありませんでした。追加したことで問題なくexpressコマンドを使用できました！

Comment: @KS 解決した場合、回答の横にチェックマークのボタンがあるかと思うので是非[回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)をしてください!